# How to programmatically calculate Max Priority Fee or TIP value EIP-1559?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereumjs, eip-1559

As per Ethereum's EIP-1559 explanation

> It is possible that miners will mine empty blocks until such time as the base fee is very low and then proceed to mine half full blocks and revert to sorting transactions by the priority fee

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md

**Static 'Priority Fee' Vs 'Dynamic Priority Fee' ?**

- If miners sort transactions based on `priority fee` or `Tip` to be get included in the next block, Is it possible that static `priority fee` results into pending transactions if the `base fee` remains same for the past or future set of blocks?
- How to pro-grammatically calculate `priority fee or Tip` to avoid pending transactions in future?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Answering your second question to calculate `maxFeePerGas` programmatically you could call this function in `ethers.js` `provider.getFeeData()` which will return `maxFeePerGas` `maxPriorityFeePerGas` `gasPrice`, however currently it seems `maxPriorityFeePerGas` is hardcoded to a value of 2.5 gwei as per their [code](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/commit/7175e2e99c2747e8d2314feb407bf0a0f9371ece).

Alchemy has the function `eth_maxpriorityfeepergas` to fetch it dynamically, which seems working well for me (even for the polygon network). Link to their [docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/apis/ethereum/eth_maxpriorityfeepergas).

Comment: Why would they hard-code 2.5 gwei :(